# nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mapping/IdentifierAccessor

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm try to use Spring + JPA + PostgreSQL.

When I click in "Debug" I get the exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mapping/IdentifierAccessor
```

The structure project is

[image]

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gastos
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = *******

spring.jpa.show-sql = true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

**Application.java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gastos4</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I didn't find a solution in the web. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not putting some dependency in the CLASSPATH, which is what NoClassDefFoundError says ... so look at the class it quotes and what are its dependencies

Comment: @NeilStockton sorry, Can you tell me how can I do it? I'm very newbie in Spring and Java world.

Answer (score 1):

try adding Spring Data Commons Core to your pom

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: the IdentifierAccessor - please refer
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mapping

Comment: I added spring-data-commons-1.9.2.RELEASE and I get a new error that says `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/type/AnnotationMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;)V`

Comment: dear,looks there are some maven dependency version mismatches

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and strangely enough I solved the problem by replacing the dependency spring-data-jpa with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```